# Expression for - Row by row variance on grouped datasets

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services

I am having troubles with creating an expression in SSRS.

I'd like to calculate the difference between two figures. The columns are in separate datasets and are grouped. They also show a total at the end of each group.

Eg

```
  Dataset 1                                  Dataset 2

Month  Workshops which Ran            Month    Workshops which Ran     Variance
Apr          40                        Apr             30                 10
May          50                        May             40                 10
Jun          45                        Jun             35                 10
Q1 Total     135                       Q1 Total        105                30
```

The quarters then carry on but, you get the picture.

Is there a way to make an expression to calculate the variance column even though the data is grouped and in different datasets?

Any help would really be appreciated :)

Will

Comment: seems like a simple join on month would work and then simply subtract to get the variance.  But if these data sets repeat months, (cover multiple years) then you'd have a problem.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume:

1. There could be voids in either data set, we could use a full outer join and coalesce.
2. You want the absolute difference for variance (no negatives)
3. You want to display the month and workshops which ran in all cases.
4. Neither dataset would span more than 1 year's period. (if they did we would need the aggregate datasets to contain year along with month and include it on the join)
5. The Q1 total value (or others) exists in both data sets and is spelled the same.

.

```
SELECT DS1.Month as [DS1 Month]
     , DS1.[Workshops which Ran] as [DS1 Workshops which Ran]
     , DS2.Month as [DS2 Month]
     , DS2.[Workshops which Ran] as [DS2 Workshops which Ran]
     , abs(coalesce(DS1.[Workshops which Ran],0) - coalesce(DS2.[Workshops which Ran],0)) as [Variance]
FROM Dataset1 DS1
FULL OUTER JOIN Dataset2 DS2
 on DS1.Month = DS2.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a dataset with all your data in one place. If you can't do this for whatever reason, and the data in the datasets is more details than the aggregated data you are showing in your example, then check this post.

http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/